# Copy output of script without running a second time

Tags: windows, cmd, command, command-prompt, prompt

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\"%username%"\Downloads\vanity\gen
@echo off
set /p Address="Test: 1"
vanitygen -X 30 1%Address%
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('vanitygen 1%Address% ^| findstr Privkey ') do echo %%a|clip&GOTO DONE
:DONE
msg "%username%" Complete!
PAUSE
```

This runs a .exe script. That script generates a completely random code each time. The script generates a code, and is displayed as text in the command prompt, but then instead generates a second code, and copies the second one instead. This means the code displayed in the command prompt, and the code in your clip board are both different. How can I make it so that the same code that is displayed, is copied to the clipboard?

Comment: The exe is running twice.  Do you only want it to run once?

Comment: Yes, I want it to copy the output from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works as you need it to:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\vanity\gen"
set /p Address="Test: 1"
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('vanitygen -X 30 1%Address% ^| findstr Privkey ') do echo %%a|clip&GOTO DONE
:DONE
msg "%username%" Complete!
PAUSE
```